# jQuery Extension accepting a String not just an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a silly question, but I can't seem to find a solution...

I just wanted to make a **isNullOrWhiteSpace** extension (same name as the .NET one), to determine if a string is `'', '0', 0, undefined, null`. Nothing crazy.

Now doing it with a typical jQuery extension, it seems it is always looking for a jQuery **Object** to be passed in. But for in my extension, I need it to work with a simple **string**, but it doesn't work at all when I do.

```
$.fn.isNullOrWhiteSpace = function () {
    if (['', '0', 0, undefined, null].indexOf($.trim(this)) > -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

'testing'.isNullOrWhiteSpace(); // doesn't work
// Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'isNullOrWhiteSpace'
```

**What am I missing here??**

-- from answers below, turns out it should be simply:

**`$.isNullOrWhiteSpace`**, the `$.fn.` part makes it a jQuery-Object extension as opposed to just a regular extension (like `$.isArray()`, `$.trim()` (which I use in my own question... sigh))

Comment: It makes no sense to do this as a  jQuery add-on.  None. Strings are not jQuery objects.

Comment: Well I know I could easily make it a Javascript `String.prototype`, but at this point I was more curious why it *doesn't* work as a jQuery add-on.

Comment: You did everything right, but `'testing'.isNullOrWhiteSpace();` should be `$('testing').isNullOrWhiteSpace();`

Comment: @IliaFrenkel: And in addition, `$.trim(this)` has to then change into `$.trim(this.selector)` as `this` is the jQuery object and `.selector` stores the string. Accepted answer seems much better off course as there is no need to go through a jQuery object wrapper.

Comment: Yeah I saw that Francois, it was my mistake to use `$.fn.`, but +1, never knew about this.selector, and this off-situation that does make it work!

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: +1 for good question. Specially because I found it very confusing myself to see what is different between `$.fn.xxx` and `$.xxx`. But the accepted answer and your question helped me understand this better now too.

Comment: Hey we both learned a lil something, always good! And yeah exactly, yours was spot on otherwise! But I had been using the incorrect method here (even though I have other extensions that are `$.whatever`, I guess I didn't realize the inherit difference! It's always the little things lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *must* hook this to jQuery — and there's really no reason to beyond namespace economy — you would do this:

```
$.nullOrWhitespace = function(s) {
  return !s || !(s.replace(/\s*/, '')); // or something like this; just an example
};
```

Then call it with

```
if ( $.nullOrWhitespace( yourString ) ) {
  ... whatever ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Ah so maybe it is that added `$.fn.` I didn't realize makes it -have- to be used on an Object! This worked perfectly. Do you personally prefer namespace methods or adding things to the Javascript prototype?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Abvcn/ - I used both the `$.` namespace method & String.prototype.

Comment: Well that covers all the bases I guess :-)

Comment: Which one do you prefer &/or use yourself?  I've read some people never add JS prototype functionality (just forget exactly why)

Comment: For something like this, if I really felt I'd get a lot of use out of it, I'd probably make a global function.  However it's not something that I've often found necessary, and the straight code to trim a string and check it for emptiness is pretty short.

Answer (score 1):

Try `String.prototype.isNullOrWhiteSpace = function() {...`

Comment: @Pointy: True that, but then null is not string :-) Maybe I misunderstood the question, its almost midnight...

Comment: I must be tired to, bc yeah it can't be null... brain fart on my part!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `$.fn.isNullOrWhiteSpace` extends jQuery.

If you are extending jQuery you propably need to call the method on a jQuery object.

`'testing'` is a string but `$('testing')` would be a jQuery object.

This seems to work:

```
$.fn.isNullOrWhiteSpace = function () {
    if (['', '0', 0, undefined, null].indexOf($.trim(this.selector)) > -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

alert($('').isNullOrWhiteSpace());
alert($('testing').isNullOrWhiteSpace());
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hw277/)

Answer (score 1):

`$.fn` by default sets the context of `this` to an array of matched elements(when used with a selector). Which you clearly don't need in this case.

```
$.isNullOrWhiteSpace = function (str) {        
     return $.inArray($.trim(str), ['', '0', 0, undefined, null]) > -1;
};
```

This is what most other utility methods do eg: `$.inArray`, `$.trim` like we have already used! :)